# Python doctests: test for None

Tags: python, doctest

Using Python 2.7 I'm trying to test that the result of a particular function call is None

I would expect these tests to pass (excuse the rather silly example)

```
def six_or_none(val):
    """
    >>> six_or_none(6)
    6
    >>> six_or_none(4)
    None
    """
    if val == 6:
        return 6
    return None
```

However they yield the following result

```
Failed example:
    six_or_none(4)
Expected:
    None
Got nothing
```

What's the correct way to test for None in doctests?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The Python interpreter *ignores* `None` return values, so doctests do the same.

Test for `is None` instead:

```
>>> six_or_none(4) is None
True
```

Comment: Martijn, do you know the motivations for ignoring None?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: `None` is the default "I have to return *something* but if I were allowed not to return anything I'd do so" return value.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: You'd never be done reading past all the `None` outputs if you did echo those.

Comment: I wonder why doctest doesn't just treat as empty an expected output solely consisting of the line "None"; perhaps the principle is to avoid surprising a user who manually checks the documented example in an interactive interpreter?

Answer (score 9):

Other option would be a direct check for `None`:

```
def six_or_none(val):
    """
    >>> six_or_none(6)
    6
    >>> six_or_none(4)
    """
    if val == 6:
        return 6
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative if you want something that looks like you might expect in your docs is:

```
>>> print(six_or_none(4))
None
```