# Why could doctests raise a NameError when run with Sphinx's `make doctest`?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest

I have a simple [function with a doctest](http://git.io/Tq2fTw), which, when run with Sphinx's `make doctest`, gives me the following error:

```
File "scheemey.rst", line ?, in default
Failed example:
    verify_balanced('asdf (foo [bar] [[baz], {}, ()]')
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1315, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest default[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        verify_balanced('asdf (foo [bar] [[baz], {}, ()]')
    NameError: name 'verify_balanced' is not defined
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the error in the question if the module with the tested function is not imported properly.

To make it work, you can use a [`testsetup`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/doctest.html#directive-testsetup) directive:

```
.. testsetup:: 

   from yourmodule import verify_balanced

>>> verify_balanced('asdf (foo) [bar] [[baz], {}, ()]')
>>> verify_balanced('asdf (foo [bar] [[baz], {}, ()]')
5
```

Note that doctest ignores `None` return values (see [Python doctests: test for None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20047519/407651)).